# LEFT JOIN not returning nulls nor the expected amount of records in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a quizzes app with this database and I am requested to print the correct answers i.e. the exam key and the answers for every user but if the user left any answer blank it should be null or an 'x' or anything to recognize it as such.

Each question has several distractors (options) but only one is correct (distractors.correct = 1) and only one answer (answers.question_id) and to check if the answer is correct answers.answer = distractor.option.
Needed output:

```
    +-----------+---------------+----------+-----------+---------------+-----------+----------+
|   exam_id |   question_id | option   |   correct |   question_id |   user_id | answer   |
|-----------+---------------+----------+-----------+---------------+-----------+----------|
|       195 |         41303 | E        |         0 |         41303 |      4404 | null     |
|       195 |         41483 | A        |         0 |         41483 |      4404 | A        |
|       195 |         41350 | A        |         0 |         41350 |      4404 | A        |
|       195 |         41401 | E        |         0 |         41401 |      4404 | E        |
|       195 |         41271 | A        |         0 |         41271 |      4404 | A        |
|       195 |         41448 | D        |         1 |         41448 |      4404 | D        |
|       195 |         41320 | E        |         1 |         41320 |      4404 | E        |
|       195 |         41499 | C        |         1 |         41499 |      4404 | C        |
|       195 |         41369 | C        |         1 |         41369 |      4404 | null     |
|       195 |         41418 | E        |         0 |         41418 |      4404 | E        |
|       195 |         41287 | D        |         1 |         41287 |      4404 | D        |
|       195 |         41467 | B        |         1 |         41467 |      4404 | B        |
|       195 |         41337 | C        |         1 |         41337 |      4404 | C        |
|       195 |         41385 | E        |         0 |         41385 |      4404 | E        |
```

Expected by client result.

```
  key DBCCDBCCABDBBADCBCCDDCCADBACDCBACCCDDBDDADAAACCACADBDCBBDDDADABBACDADCBDABADCCAACCBBBABBACAAADXADCAABBBBCDDADCCBDBACDCABDABDACACAC
    0001 DBCCBBCCBBBBBADBXXXXDCBABBACDCBACCCDDBDCADAAABCAADCBDCBBDDDDDCBBACDABCBDDBACACAACCBBBAABACABDDBCDCBABCBBCDDADCCBDBACDCDCDBDBCCACAC
    0002 DACCBBCCCBDDBAACBCCDCBBABAABDCBACCCDDBDCACAAACCADABBDCBCADDDDABBBCAADCBDABACCCABBDCDBDCDADABBDDBACBABBDBDDDADCCBDBABBCDBDADBBCACAB
    0003 CCCCCBCCBBDCBBDCBCCADCAABAAADCBABCCDCCDCADAAABCADABBCCBBBDBADABBACDADCBAABACBCCCCDCDCAADACABADBCCCBABBDDCDDDDCCBBBACDCDBDDBBACADAC
    0004 CCDACBCCBBDDBADBBCCBABBADBACDCBACCCDDCDCADAAACCADADBDCBADDDDDABBACAACCBCACACCCAACCBBBAAAACABBDAACCCABBDBCDDADCCBDBACDCACBADCCCACAC
    0005 CCDCCBCCABDDBADCBCCCDCBACBABDCBACCCDDBDCADAAABDDDDDDDABADDDBDABBACDAACBDACADDCCACCBBBACBACADADBADCBABBABCDDADCCBDBACDCADDBDBACADAC
    0006 CCCCCBCCABDDCADCBCDCDCAACBACDCBABACDDBDCADAADCCADACCAABABDDBDABBACDABCADABADAACACCDBBABBACADBDCADCAACBDBCDDADCCBDBABDCABDABBBBDCAC
```

I know that this would include a transpose that I do not need since I will process the results in php within an array/collection.
The first row has all the right answers/options
the next rows have the answers of each user.

Tried this:

```
select answers.exam_id, distractors.question_id, distractors.option, distractors.correct, answers.question_id, answers.user_id, answers.answer
                        from distractors
                        LEFT JOIN answers on distractors.question_id = answers.question_id
                        AND answers.answer = distractors.option
                        AND answers.user_id = 4404
                        WHERE answers.exam_id = 195
                        ORDER BY answers.user_id
                        ;



    +-----------+---------------+----------+-----------+---------------+-----------+----------+
|   exam_id |   question_id | option   |   correct |   question_id |   user_id | answer   |
|-----------+---------------+----------+-----------+---------------+-----------+----------|
|       195 |         41263 | C        |         1 |         41263 |      4404 | C        |
|       195 |         41259 | C        |         0 |         41259 |      4404 | C        |
|       195 |         41260 | E        |         0 |         41260 |      4404 | E        |
|       195 |         41261 | B        |         0 |         41261 |      4404 | B        |
|       195 |         41262 | E        |         0 |         41262 |      4404 | E        |
|       195 |         41264 | C        |         1 |         41264 |      4404 | C        |
|       195 |         41265 | E        |         1 |         41265 |      4404 | E        |
|       195 |         41266 | A        |         0 |         41266 |      4404 | A        |
|       195 |         41267 | A        |         0 |         41267 |      4404 | A        |
|       195 |         41268 | A        |         1 |         41268 |      4404 | A        |
|       195 |         41269 | E        |         0 |         41269 |      4404 | E        |
|       195 |         41270 | B        |         0 |         41270 |      4404 | B        |
|       195 |         41271 | A        |         0 |         41271 |      4404 | A        |
|       195 |         41272 | C        |         0 |         41272 |      4404 | C        |
|       195 |         41273 | E        |         0 |         41273 |      4404 | E        |
|       195 |         41274 | A        |         0 |         41274 |      4404 | A        |
|       195 |         41275 | E        |         0 |         41275 |      4404 | E        |
|       195 |         41276 | C        |         0 |         41276 |      4404 | C        |
|       195 |         41277 | D        |         1 |         41277 |      4404 | D        |
|       195 |         41278 | D        |         0 |         41278 |      4404 | D        |
|       195 |         41279 | C        |         1 |         41279 |      4404 | C        |
|       195 |         41280 | B        |         1 |         41280 |      4404 | B        |
|       195 |         41282 | D        |         0 |         41282 |      4404 | D        |
|       195 |         41281 | E        |         1 |         41281 |      4404 | E        |
|       195 |         41283 | D        |         0 |         41283 |      4404 | D        |
|       195 |         41284 | D        |         1 |         41284 |      4404 | D        |
|       195 |         41285 | E        |         1 |         41285 |      4404 | E        |
|       195 |         41286 | C        |         1 |         41286 |      4404 | C        |
|       195 |         41287 | D        |         1 |         41287 |      4404 | D        |
|       195 |         41288 | A        |         1 |         41288 |      4404 | A        |
|       195 |         41290 | C        |         1 |         41290 |      4404 | C        |
|       195 |         41289 | B        |         1 |         41289 |      4404 | B        |
|       195 |         41291 | E        |         1 |         41291 |      4404 | E        |
|       195 |         41292 | B        |         1 |         41292 |      4404 | B        |
|       195 |         41293 | C        |         1 |         41293 |      4404 | C        |
|       195 |         41294 | D        |         1 |         41294 |      4404 | D        |
|       195 |         41296 | A        |         0 |         41296 |      4404 | A        |
|       195 |         41295 | C        |         1 |         41295 |      4404 | C        |
|       195 |         41297 | E        |         0 |         41297 |      4404 | E        |
|       195 |         41298 | C        |         0 |         41298 |      4404 | C        |
|       195 |         41299 | E        |         0 |         41299 |      4404 | E        |
|       195 |         41300 | B        |         0 |         41300 |      4404 | B        |
|       195 |         41301 | A        |         1 |         41301 |      4404 | A        |
|       195 |         41302 | B        |         0 |         41302 |      4404 | B        |
|       195 |         41303 | E        |         0 |         41303 |      4404 | E        |

|       195 |         41511 | A        |         0 |         41511 |      4404 | A        |
|       195 |         41512 | C        |         0 |         41512 |      4404 | C        |
|       195 |         41513 | B        |         1 |         41513 |      4404 | B        |
+-----------+---------------+----------+-----------+---------------+-----------+----------+
245 rows in set
```

Not getting the expected 321 questions/answers with the accompanying nulls.

I tried several joins but none gives the expected results.

Tables:

```
DESCRIBE answers;
+-------------+------------------+--------+-------+-----------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null   | Key   |   Default | Extra          |
|-------------+------------------+--------+-------+-----------+----------------|
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO     | PRI   |    <null> | auto_increment |
| user_id     | int(10) unsigned | NO     | MUL   |    <null> |                |
| question_id | int(10) unsigned | NO     | MUL   |    <null> |                |
| answer      | char(255)        | YES    |       |    <null> |                |
| created_at  | timestamp        | YES    |       |    <null> |                |
| updated_at  | timestamp        | YES    |       |    <null> |                |
| deleted_at  | timestamp        | YES    |       |    <null> |                |
| exam_id     | int(10) unsigned | NO     |       |    <null> |                |
+-------------+------------------+--------+-------+-----------+----------------+
8 rows in set
Time: 0.006s
    DESCRIBE questions;
+------------+------------------+--------+-------+-----------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null   | Key   |   Default | Extra          |
|------------+------------------+--------+-------+-----------+----------------|
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO     | PRI   |    <null> | auto_increment |
| slot_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO     | MUL   |    <null> |                |
| order      | smallint(6)      | NO     |       |    <null> |                |
| text       | text             | NO     |       |    <null> |                |
| created_at | timestamp        | YES    |       |    <null> |                |
| updated_at | timestamp        | YES    |       |    <null> |                |
+------------+------------------+--------+-------+-----------+----------------+
6 rows in set
Time: 0.008s

DESCRIBE distractors;
+-------------+------------------+--------+-------+-----------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null   | Key   |   Default | Extra          |
|-------------+------------------+--------+-------+-----------+----------------|
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO     | PRI   |    <null> | auto_increment |
| question_id | int(10) unsigned | NO     | MUL   |    <null> |                |
| option      | varchar(255)     | NO     |       |    <null> |                |
| distractor  | text             | NO     |       |    <null> |                |
| correct     | tinyint(1)       | NO     |       |    <null> |                |
| created_at  | timestamp        | YES    |       |    <null> |                |
| updated_at  | timestamp        | YES    |       |    <null> |                |
+-------------+------------------+--------+-------+-----------+----------------+
7 rows in set
Time: 0.006s

    describe exams;
+---------------+------------------+--------+-------+-----------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null   | Key   |   Default | Extra          |
|---------------+------------------+--------+-------+-----------+----------------|
| id            | int(10) unsigned | NO     | PRI   |    <null> | auto_increment |
| applicated_at | datetime         | NO     |       |    <null> |                |
| board_id      | int(10)          | NO     |       |    <null> |                |
| active        | tinyint(1)       | NO     |       |         1 |                |
| duration      | int(10) unsigned | NO     |       |    <null> |                |
| passing_grade | int(10)          | YES    |       |    <null> |                |
| annotation    | text             | NO     |       |    <null> |                |
| deleted_at    | timestamp        | YES    |       |    <null> |                |
| created_at    | timestamp        | YES    |       |    <null> |                |
| updated_at    | timestamp        | YES    |       |    <null> |                |
+---------------+------------------+--------+-------+-----------+----------------+
10 rows in set
Time: 0.014s
```

Sample data:

```
select * from distractors limit 1000;

    +------+---------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|   id |   question_id | option   | distractor                                                                                             |   correct | created_at          | updated_at          |
|------+---------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------|
|    1 |             1 | A        | Diuresis osmótica                                                                                      |         0 | 2017-01-12 21:20:29 | 2017-01-12 21:20:29 |
|    2 |             1 | B        | Diabetes insípida central                                                                              |         1 | 2017-01-12 21:20:29 | 2017-01-12 21:20:29 |
|    3 |             1 | C        | Diabetes insípida nefrogénica                                                                          |         0 | 2017-01-12 21:20:29 | 2017-01-12 21:20:29 |
|    4 |             1 | D        | Administración de soluciones hipertónicas                                                              |         0 | 2017-01-12 21:20:29 | 2017-01-12 21:20:29 |
|    5 |             1 | E        | Sx de secreción inapropiada de hormona antidiurética                                                   |         0 | 2017-01-12 21:20:29 | 2017-01-12 21:20:29 |
|    6 |             2 | A        | TC cerebral                                                                                            |         0 | 2017-01-12 21:20:29 | 2017-01-12 21:20:29 |
|    7 |             2 | B        | Sodio urinario                                                                                         |         0 | 2017-01-12 21:20:29 | 2017-01-12 21:20:29 |
|    8 |             2 | C        | Osmolaridad sérica                                                                                     |         0 | 2017-01-12 21:20:30 | 2017-01-12 21:20:30 |
|    9 |             2 | D        | Osmolaridad urinaria                                                                                   |         0 | 2017-01-12 21:20:30 | 2017-01-12 21:20:30 |
|   10 |             2 | E        | Respuesta a vasopresina                                                                                |         1 | 2017-01-12 21:20:30 | 2017-01-12 21:20:30 |
|   11 |             3 | A        | Pérdida extrarrenal de agua                                                                            |         0 | 2017-01-12 21:20:30 | 2017-01-12 21:20:30 |
|   12 |             3 | B        | Aumento en la reabsorción de sodio                                                                     |         0 | 2017-01-12 21:20:30 | 2017-01-12 21:20:30 |
|   13 |             3 | C        | Aumento en la depuración de agua libre                                                                 |         1 | 2017-01-12 21:20:30 | 2017-01-12 21:20:30 |
|   14 |             3 | D        | Disminución en la depuración de agua libre                                                             |         0 | 2017-01-12 21:20:30 | 2017-01-12 21:20:30 |
|   15 |             3 | E        | Resistencia tubular a la acción de la hormona antidiurética                                            |         0 | 2017-01-12 21:20:30 | 2017-01-12 21:20:30 |
|   16 |             4 | A        | Solución Hartmann                                                                                      |         0 | 2017-01-12 21:20:30 | 2017-01-12 21:20:30 |
|   17 |             4 | B        | Solución salina al 3%                                                                                  |         0 | 2017-01-12 21:20:30 | 2017-01-12 21:20:30 |
|   18 |             4 | C        | Solución salina al 0.9%                                                                                |         0 | 2017-01-12 21:20:30 | 2017-01-12 21:20:30 |
|   19 |             4 | D        | Solución glucosada al 5 %                                                                              |         0 | 2017-01-12 21:20:30 | 2017-01-12 21:20:30 |
|   20 |             4 | E        | Solución isotónica con HCO<sub>3</sub>                                                                 |         1 | 2017-01-12 21:20:30 | 2017-01-12 21:20:30 |
|   21 |             5 | A        | Mielinólisis                                                                                           |         0 | 2017-01-12 21:20:30 | 2017-01-12 21:20:30 |
|   22 |             5 | B        | Edema cerebral                                                                                         |         1 | 2017-01-12 21:20:30 | 2017-01-12 21:20:30 |

select * from distractors limit 1000

+------+-----------+---------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+-----------+
|   id |   user_id |   question_id | answer   | created_at          | updated_at          |   deleted_at |   exam_id |
|------+-----------+---------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+-----------|
|   26 |      2782 |             1 | B        | 2017-01-14 15:20:39 | 2017-01-14 15:20:39 |       <null> |         1 |
|   27 |      2755 |             1 | B        | 2017-01-14 15:20:39 | 2017-01-14 15:20:39 |       <null> |         1 |
|   28 |      2741 |             1 | B        | 2017-01-14 15:20:42 | 2017-01-14 15:20:42 |       <null> |         1 |
|   29 |      2755 |             2 | E        | 2017-01-14 15:20:51 | 2017-01-14 15:20:51 |       <null> |         1 |
|   30 |      2755 |             3 | C        | 2017-01-14 15:21:11 | 2017-01-14 15:21:11 |       <null> |         1 |
|   31 |      2755 |             4 | D        | 2017-01-14 15:21:25 | 2017-01-14 15:21:25 |       <null> |         1 |
|   32 |      2741 |             2 | E        | 2017-01-14 15:21:34 | 2017-01-14 15:21:34 |       <null> |         1 |
|   33 |      2763 |             1 | B        | 2017-01-14 15:21:39 | 2017-01-14 15:21:39 |       <null> |         1 |
|   34 |      2782 |             4 | D        | 2017-01-14 15:21:40 | 2017-01-14 15:21:40 |       <null> |         1 |
|   35 |      2755 |             5 | B        | 2017-01-14 15:21:52 | 2017-01-14 15:21:52 |       <null> |         1 |
|   36 |      2782 |             5 | B        | 2017-01-14 15:22:06 | 2017-01-14 15:22:06 |       <null> |         1 |
|   37 |      2763 |             2 | D        | 2017-01-14 15:22:07 | 2017-01-14 15:22:07 |       <null> |         1 |
|   38 |      2775 |           116 | E        | 2017-01-14 15:22:19 | 2017-01-14 15:22:19 |       <null> |         1 |
|   39 |      2775 |           117 | A        | 2017-01-14 15:22:23 | 2017-01-14 16:59:31 |       <null> |         1 |
|   40 |      2801 |            21 | B        | 2017-01-14 15:22:25 | 2017-01-14 15:22:25 |       <null> |         1 |
|   41 |      2775 |           118 | A        | 2017-01-14 15:22:29 | 2017-01-14 15:22:29 |       <null> |         1 |
|   42 |      2868 |           301 | C        | 2017-01-14 15:22:30 | 2017-01-14 15:22:47 |       <null> |         2 |
|   43 |      2763 |             3 | C        | 2017-01-14 15:22:36 | 2017-01-14 15:22:36 |       <null> |         1 |
|   44 |      2775 |           119 | D        | 2017-01-14 15:22:37 | 2017-01-14 15:22:37 |       <null> |         1 |
|   45 |      2801 |            22 | C        | 2017-01-14 15:22:40 | 2017-01-14 15:22:40 |       <null> |         1 |
|   46 |      2734 |             1 | B        | 2017-01-14 15:22:41 | 2017-01-14 15:22:41 |       <null> |         1 |
|   47 |      2799 |            16 | C        | 2017-01-14 15:22:41 | 2017-01-14 15:22:41 |       <null> |         1 |
|   48 |      2782 |             2 | D        | 2017-01-14 15:22:48 | 2017-01-14 15:25:11 |       <null> |         1 |
|   49 |      2798 |             1 | B        | 2017-01-14 15:22:51 | 2017-01-14 15:22:51 |       <null> |         1 |
|   50 |      2803 |            21 | B        | 2017-01-14 15:22:51 | 2017-01-14 15:22:51 |       <null> |         1 |
|   51 |      2795 |            36 | B        | 2017-01-14 15:22:54 | 2017-01-14 15:22:54 |       <null> |         1 |
|   52 |      2803 |            22 | C        | 2017-01-14 15:22:54 | 2017-01-14 15:22:54 |       <null> |         1 |
|   53 |      2781 |            41 | D        | 2017-01-14 15:22:59 | 2017-01-14 15:22:59 |       <null> |         1 |
|   54 |      2862 |           321 | B        | 2017-01-14 15:23:01 | 2017-01-14 15:23:01 |       <null> |         2 |
|   55 |      2764 |            31 | A        | 2017-01-14 15:23:01 | 2017-01-14 15:23:01 |       <null> |         1 |
|   56 |      2769 |            21 | B        | 2017-01-14 15:23:02 | 2017-01-14 15:23:02 |       <null> |         1 |
|   57 |      2755 |             6 | A        | 2017-01-14 15:23:02 | 2017-01-14 15:23:03 |       <null> |         1 |
|   58 |      2871 |           302 | A        | 2017-01-14 15:23:03 | 2017-01-14 15:27:40 |       <null> |         2 |
|   59 |      2803 |            24 | E        | 2017-01-14 15:23:03 | 2017-01-14 15:23:03 |       <null> |         1 |
|   60 |      2868 |           302 | C        | 2017-01-14 15:23:04 | 2017-01-14 15:23:04 |       <null> |         2 |
|   61 |      2862 |           322 | E        | 2017-01-14 15:23:13 | 2017-01-14 15:23:13 |       <null> |         2 |
|   62 |      2799 |            17 | C        | 2017-01-14 15:23:15 | 2017-01-14 15:23:15 |       <null> |         1 |
|   63 |      2769 |            22 | C        | 2017-01-14 15:23:16 | 2017-01-14 15:23:16 |       <null> |         1 |
|   64 |      2741 |             3 | C        | 2017-01-14 15:23:17 | 2017-01-14 15:23:17 |       <null> |         1 |

select * from exams;
+------+---------------------+------------+----------+------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|   id | applicated_at       |   board_id |   active |   duration |   passing_grade | annotation                                                      |   deleted_at | created_at          | updated_at          |
|------+---------------------+------------+----------+------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------|
|    1 | 2017-01-14 09:00:00 |         32 |        1 |        180 |          <null> |                                                                 |       <null> | 2017-01-12 21:22:08 | 2017-01-12 21:22:08 |
|    2 | 2017-01-14 09:05:00 |         32 |        1 |        180 |          <null> |                                                                 |       <null> | 2017-01-12 21:25:14 | 2017-01-12 21:25:14 |
|   12 | 2017-01-19 16:00:00 |         13 |        1 |        180 |             120 |                                                                 |       <null> | 2017-01-17 19:44:00 | 2017-01-17 19:44:00 |
|   42 | 2017-02-01 16:00:00 |         41 |        1 |        250 |               0 |                                                                 |       <null> | 2017-01-30 12:40:21 | 2017-01-30 12:40:21 |
|   62 | 2017-03-03 11:00:00 |         48 |        1 |         60 |          <null> | Biología Molecular 2                                            |       <null> | 2017-01-31 20:59:19 | 2017-01-31 20:59:19 |
|   88 | 2017-03-03 12:30:00 |         49 |        1 |         70 |          <null> | Citogenética 2                                                  |       <null> | 2017-02-01 04:49:44 | 2017-02-01 04:49:44 |
|   99 | 2017-02-17 17:00:00 |         28 |        1 |        120 |          <null> | Examen de 130 reactivos                                         |       <null> | 2017-02-16 16:01:08 | 2017-02-16 16:01:08 |
|  109 | 2017-02-23 09:00:00 |         34 |        1 |        180 |          <null> | Examen de 65 casos Neuro fisiología                             |       <null> | 2017-02-21 18:37:57 | 2017-02-21 18:37:57 |
|  112 | 2017-02-25 09:00:00 |         47 |        1 |        180 |          <null> | Examen de 61 casos en Tlatelolco                                |       <null> | 2017-02-21 22:03:19 | 2017-02-21 22:03:19 |
|  121 | 2017-02-25 10:00:00 |         41 |        1 |        240 |          <null> | Examen de 71 casos en Universisad Anuahuac                      |       <null> | 2017-02-21 22:31:37 | 2017-02-21 22:31:37 |
|  123 | 2017-02-25 09:00:00 |         18 |        1 |        180 |          <null> | Examen de 60 casos hematología adultos                          |       <null> | 2017-02-22 13:50:20 | 2017-02-22 13:50:20 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer assumes that you only want to include those users' results, that actually took an exam (answered at least 1 question).

Since I do not know if you have any tables that shows who subscribed to what exam (you should if you do not), I have to create the list of users that took the exams by obtaining all distinct exam id - user id pairs in a subquery as a derived table.

Also, there is a disconnect between the exams and the questions table - probably there is a slots table that connects the two tables. Because of this disconnect, I'm forced to use the answers table in a derived table to join exams and questions. However, this means that questions asked at the different slots for the same exam cannot be distinguished from each other. Also, this means that if all users skipped the same question, then it will not show up in the results.

I `inner join` the question and the correct options from the distractors table on the derived tables and left join the users' answers on this. I will use parentheses in the joins to force MySQL to create the exams - users - questions - correct answers resultset first and then do the left join.

```
select t1.exam_id, t2.question_id, d.option, (d.option=a.answer) as correct, t1.user_id, a.answer
from
    (
     (select distinct exam_id, user_id from answers) t1
     inner join
     (select distinct exam_id, question_id from answers) t2 a on t1.exam_id=t2.exam_id
     inner join questions q on t2.question_id=q.id
     inner join distractors d on q.id=d.question_id and d.correct=1
    )
left join answers a on t1.exam_id=a.exam_id and t1.user_id=a.user_id and q.id=a.question_id
```

Comment: Thank you very much it is just the right thing!!. At this moment it is a bit over my head but works like a charm. Will update the question with the output of your query. Thanks again @Shadow

Comment: There is a `exam_user` table that relates the user with the exams. Also there is a `slots` table that relates among other tables the questions with the exam. Think of the slot as a group of n>0 questions to be presented at the same time to the user. If you think it can be improved by this details let me know and thanks again @Shadow.

Comment: You can use these tables in place of the derived tables. The query would probably run faster (depending on how the data looks like in those tables).

Comment: Perfect!! I will try it and let you know. You have been really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are randomly trying things with no real understanding of how the tables relate to each other or the data you want. You need to approach this systematically and with an understanding of the meaning of the data. Not just try joins at random.

I would suggest breaking it down into steps and then adding each new piece of information and checking results one step at a time. This helps you isolate the exact point where the information started to no longer make sense if you have a problem. It is also helpful if you start with one exam and one user and get everything straight with a small data set first before removing those conditions.

First you need to know which questions belong to which exam and what the correct answer is. Because you don't ever need questions and answers without the relationship to each other, these will most likely need to be inner joins.

Then you need to add a join to the users who have taken the exam. Note this join needs to be to the exam not the question if you are to handle questions they did not answer. Since you are only interested in exams which have users who have answered them, then this needs to be an inner join.

Then you add in the answers the users gave to the questions in the exam. Now you use the left join because there will be some questions unanswered by the users who took the exam.

Then you can compare their answer with the correct answer.

I can't make out what a distractor is, so I haven't included this. Somehow if you need it, you will need to understand how this relates to the meaning of the rest. Once you understand the meaning, the syntax becomes clear.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. But I think they are not random. So far I managed to grade the users using joins and to count the amount of answers and correct and incorrect answers all this relating the answers with the distractors and filtering using answers.exam_id. The distractor is the option as in multiple option tests A), B), C) etc. I the again most of the calculations related to the exam such as all the grades by subject and by "school" and mean, variance, reliability index etc I can calculate them based on my queries is the join part to get the vacant answers that I cannot grasp yet.

Comment: @MarcoSantana I'm sorry, but I agree with HLGEM, your tries seem to be quite random. Why? Because each has a completely different list of fields in the output and even different list of tables. Unfortunately, this answers seems to be a large comment, not really an answer :S

Comment: I thank you the comments and the input @Shadow and HLGEM. Those tries where only tests to see why I couldn't get the vacant answers (null fields). Either way I added the expected output and what my client asked for.